# Anylogic: how to export a model without Anylogic cloud?

Tags: image, model, png, jpeg, anylogic

I am using the PLE of Anylogic. I would like to know if it is possible to export a model of Anylogic as PNG or JPEG. I don't want to use Anylogic cloud but I simply need an image of the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One available option is the "Create documentation" which you can find under the "Tools" button in the top toolbar. This will create a PDF with images of your model as well as tables summarizing all your code and parameters' values.

But if you only need an image, why not just take a screenshot? You can also select all your model's element, copy and paste in Paint for example.

Is that what you need? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I can't take a screenshot because the model is too big but I used the "create documentation" and it's perfect. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: To resolve the screenshot issue, you can also, like I mentioned, select all the elements, copy them and paste them in an application such as Paint.

Answer (score 0):

In case your model is too big, you can do several things (from easiest to hardest):

1. make several screenshots, and then get them together
2. use the zoom to get a wider view and get the whole picture in one
3. use viewAreas of different size to view whatever you need to do
4. change your UX so as to see different information in different views (and then screenshot whatever you find more useful from those views)